# how to get all available bluetooth devices android c# xamarin

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, xamarin.android

i want to get all bluetooth devices in a list view this code works in java but i want it by c# xamarin any help please?

```
  private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
        // object and its info from the Intent.
        BluetoothDevice device = 
        intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        String deviceName = device.getName();
        String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
    }
}
```

};

Answer (score 5):

First, get an instance of the default `BluetoothAdapter` on the Android device and check if it is enabled:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;  
if(adapter == null)  
    throw new Exception("No Bluetooth adapter found.");

if(!adapter.IsEnabled)  
    throw new Exception("Bluetooth adapter is not enabled.");
```

Then get an instance of the `BluetoothDevice` representing the physical device you’re connecting to. You can get a list of currently paired devices using the adapter’s `BondedDevices` collection. I use some simple `LINQ` to find the device I’m looking for:

```
BluetoothDevice device = (from bd in adapter.BondedDevices  
                          where bd.Name == "NameOfTheDevice" select bd).FirstOrDefault();

if(device == null)  
    throw new Exception("Named device not found.");
```

Finally, use the device’s `CreateRfCommSocketToServiceRecord` method, which will return a `BluetoothSocket` that can be used for connection and communication. Note that the `UUID` specified below is the standard `UUID` for `SPP`:

```
_socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));  
await _socket.ConnectAsync();
```

Now that the device is connected, communication occurs via the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` properties which live on the `BluetoothSocket` object These properties are standard .NET Stream objects and can be used exactly as you’d expect:

```
// Read data from the device
await _socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

// Write data to the device
await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: This is almost identical to https://brianpeek.com/connect-to-a-bluetooth-device-with-xamarinandroid/ , Author: Brian Peek, Date: April 27, 2014. Unless you are the original author, please credit the original source. [No license stated at that link, the blog author worked at Microsoft, and it is simple code fundamental to using Bluetooth on Android, so I don't think there is any copyright issue. Just need to say where the code and explanation came from.]